# オブジェクトの値に応じてキーを削除するには？

Tags: javascript, array

以下のような配列があったとして,

```
const items = [
  { 'id': 1, 'category': -1, 'question': -1, 'answer': -1 },
  { 'id': 2, 'category': -1, 'question': 0, 'answer': -1 },
  { 'id': 3, 'category': -1, 'question': -1, 'answer': 3 },
  { 'id': 4, 'category': -1, 'question': -1, 'answer': -1 },
]
```

この配列内に格納されている各オブジェクトに対して値が `0` 未満であるキーを削除したい場合, つまり

```
const items = [
  { 'id': 1 },
  { 'id': 2, 'question': 0 },
  { 'id': 3, 'answer': 3 },
  { 'id': 4 },
]
```

以上のような結果を得たい場合, どのような方法が考えられるでしょうか？
ライブラリとして [lodash](https://lodash.com/) が使える環境になります.

Comment: lodash であれば [\_.omitBy(object, \[predicate=\_.identity\])](https://lodash.com/docs/#omitBy) を使うと良さそうです。`items.map(i => _.omitBy(i, e => e < 0))`

Comment: @metropolis 簡潔でエレガントな方法をご教示頂きありがとうございます.

Comment: もし問題が解決した場合は、解決した方法を可能な限り詳しく回答として投稿し、質問を解決済みにしていただけませんか？

Comment: @supa かしこまりました. もう暫くオープンにさせていただけませんか？

Answer (score 1):

コメントにすでに回答があるので二番煎じではありますが、lodashを使わないパターンを記しておきます。

```js
const items = [
  { id: 1, category: -1, question: -1, answer: -1 },
  { id: 2, category: -1, question: 0, answer: -1 },
  { id: 3, category: -1, question: -1, answer: 3 },
  { id: 4, category: -1, question: -1, answer: -1 },
];

/**
 * 愚直に書いた場合
 */
const result1 = items.map(item =>
  Object.entries(item)
    .filter(([, value]) => value >= 0)
    .reduce((all, [key, value]) => ({ ...all, [key]: value }), {}),
);

/**
 * 今回の処理をフィルタリングの処理を任意に出来るように関数化した場合
 */
function pickBy(list, filterFunction) {
  return list.map((obj) =>
    Object.entries(obj)
      .filter(([key, value]) => filterFunction(key, value))
      .reduce((all, [key, value]) => ({ ...all, [key]: value }), {}),
  );
}

const result2 = pickBy(items, (_, value) => value >= 0);

console.log("==== result1 ====");
console.log(JSON.stringify(result1, null, 2));
console.log("==== result2 ====");
console.log(JSON.stringify(result2, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

「キーを削除」という表現から、**破壊的処理**を期待していると想定しました。
`delete` 演算子でプロパティを削除することが出来ます。

```js
'use strict';
const items = [
  { 'id': 1, 'category': -1, 'question': -1, 'answer': -1 },
  { 'id': 2, 'category': -1, 'question': 0, 'answer': -1 },
  { 'id': 3, 'category': -1, 'question': -1, 'answer': 3 },
  { 'id': 4, 'category': -1, 'question': -1, 'answer': -1 },
];

for (let item of items) {
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
    if (value < 0) {
      delete item[key];
    }
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(items)); // [{"id":1},{"id":2,"question":0},{"id":3,"answer":3},{"id":4}]
```

Re: hitenMITSURUGIstyle さん